# Retrieving Data from Cache in Spring boot Cacheable

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-cache

I want to implement two methods in service class.
One method will take array of names as argument , will retrieve all its objects and store objects into cache.

```
@Cacheable(value="HeaderConfig")
public List<HeaderConfig> getHeadeConfigByFieldNames(String[] fieldNames)
{
    List<HeaderConfig> hcList = new ArrayList<HeaderConfig>();
    for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
        hcList.add(headerConfigRepository.getHeadeConfigByFieldName(fieldName));
    }
    return hcList;
}
```

Another method will take name as an argument and it should fetch Object from cached record,that was done in previous method.

```
@Cacheable(value="HeaderConfig" , key ="#fieldName")
 public HeaderConfig getHeadeConfigByFieldName(String fieldName)
{
    System.out.println("from database");
    HeaderConfig hc = null;
    // CODE TO BE IMPLEMENTED TO GET DATA FROM CACHE
    return hc;
}
```

Please can anyone suggest how to process here. Do I need to configure any cache manager .

Comment: That's not how a "cache" works, that's just a regular in-memory data structure. You use `@Cacheable` by just using the getter regularly, and Spring takes care of inserting into/retrieving from the cache for you.

Comment: Thanks. So here I should give my own implementation in plain java code.

Comment: Just retrieve your data from the database and pretend that the cache doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First method is not needed. Instead, the second method can be called in a loop. Spring will automatically take care of caching and retrieving.

Just make sure that the second method is called on an autowired/Spring Injected instance of Bean in which it is implemented directly, Not through some method in the bean itself.